# Export to excel function Not geeting triggered from ViewModel In WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi i have a button i have added the button commands that should get trigger on button press but my function 'WriteDataIntoExcelSheet' and "WriteHeaderIntoExcelSheet" is not getting called. please help me i am new to WPF MVVM this is happening because my vm object in ListViewExcelExporterExtension class is getting null please help me or suggest some edits. My project is on github https://github.com/riteshraj96/WPF_MVVM_Demo/tree/MVVM_Development and its working except export to excel.

[image]

UserView.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMDemo.UserRegistrationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
    Title="Registration Window" Height="300" Width="575.851">
    <Window.Resources>

        <viewmodel:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <viewmodel:DatetimeToDateConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Student.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="76,0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Age" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Student.Age, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Content="Export to excel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,6.45,0,0" Grid.Row="4" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85.281" RenderTransformOrigin="0.185,0.694"
                v:ListViewExcelExporterExtension.ExcelExporter="{Binding ElementName=lstStudentData}"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FillCourseId}"  Name="cmb_CourseIDName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164.191,5,0,0" 
                  Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168.342" Grid.RowSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"  FontSize="8" IsReadOnly="True" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Student.SCourseIDName,Mode=TwoWay}" RenderTransformOrigin="1.431,0.77">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseID, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ComboBox>
        <ListView x:Name="lstStudentData" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,31.098,10"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="151.981" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView  >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="80"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Joining Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JoiningDate, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Width="90" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Course Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SCourseIDName.CourseName}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="CourseId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SCourseIDName.CourseID}" Width="60"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

ListViewExcelExporter
The funtion in ViewMOdel ExportTo Excel and write header is not getting triggered.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

using MVVMDemo;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class ListViewExcelExporterExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ExcelExporter Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExcelExporterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ExcelExporter",
            typeof(ListView), typeof(ListViewExcelExporterExtension),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnExcelExportRequest)));


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the ExcelExporter property. 
        /// </summary>
        public static ListView GetExcelExporter(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (ListView)d.GetValue(ExcelExporterProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the ExcelExporter property. 
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetExcelExporter(DependencyObject d, ListView value)
        {
            d.SetValue(ExcelExporterProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the FilterSource property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnExcelExportRequest(DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Button button = d as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
            ListView listView = e.NewValue as ListView;

            if ((button != null) && (listView != null))
            {
                button.Click += delegate (object sender, RoutedEventArgs er)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application =
                        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    application.Visible = true;

                    // Workaround to fix MCST bug - The threads culture info must be en-US for the Excel sheet
                    //                              to open properly
                    CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

                    Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
                    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
                    if (worksheet != null)
                    {
                        // Set the display to show from left to right
                        worksheet._DisplayRightToLeft = 0;

                        if (listView.Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            // Write the header
                            IEnhancedListObject vm = listView.Items[0] as IEnhancedListObject;
                            int nRow = 1;
                            int nColumn = 1;
                            if (vm != null)
                            {
                                vm.WriteHeaderIntoExcelSheet(worksheet, ref nRow, ref nColumn);
                            }
                            // Write all the elements in the view model
                            foreach (var item in listView.Items)
                            {
                                vm = item as IEnhancedListObject;
                                vm.WriteDataIntoExcelSheet(worksheet, ref nRow, ref nColumn);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Work around MSFT bug - return the culture info to the previous set
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase, IEnhancedListObject 
    {
        static String connectionString = @"Data Source=Ramco-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SIT_Ramco_DB;Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        private Student _student;
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
        private ICommand _SubmitCommand;

        public Student Student
        {
            get
            {
                return _student;
            }
            set
            {
                _student = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Student");
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _fillCourseId = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        public ObservableCollection<Student> FillCourseId
        {
            get { return _fillCourseId; }
            set
            {
                _fillCourseId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SystemStatusData");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get
            {
                return _students;
            }
            set
            {
                _students = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
            }
        }

        private Student _selectedcourseIdname;

        public Student SelectedCourseIdName
        {
            get { return _selectedcourseIdname; }
            set
            {
                _selectedcourseIdname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCourseIdName");

            }

        }
        public string SelectedCourseId
        {
            get { return _selectedcourseIdname.CourseID; }
            set
            {
                _selectedcourseIdname.CourseID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCourseId");

            }

        }


        public string SelectedCourseName
        {
            get { return _selectedcourseIdname.CourseName; }
            set
            {
                _selectedcourseIdname.CourseName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCourseName");

            }

        }

        public ICommand SubmitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SubmitCommand == null)
                {
                    _SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Submit(),
                        null);
                }
                return _SubmitCommand;
            }
        }

        //********************************************* Functions*******************************************// 

        public void GetCourseIdFromDB()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dev_Course", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                // Student Student = new Student();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    FillCourseId.Add(new Student
                    {
                        CourseID = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                        CourseName = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()
                    });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Student = new Student();
            Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            Students.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Students_CollectionChanged);
            GetCourseIdFromDB();
        }

        void Students_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
        }

        private void Submit()
        {
            Student.JoiningDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
            //Students.Add(SelectedCourseIdName);
            Students.Add(Student);
            Student = new Student();
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Write the header into the Excel sheet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="worksheet"></param>
        /// <param name="nRow"></param>
        /// <param name="nColumn"></param>
        public void WriteHeaderIntoExcelSheet(Worksheet worksheet, ref int nRow, ref int nColumn)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn] = "NAME";
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 1] = "AGE";
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 2] = "JOINING DATE";
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 3] = "COURSE NAME";
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 4] = "COURSE ID";
            nRow++;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write the Companies data into Excel sheet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="worksheet"></param>
        /// <param name="nRow"></param>
        /// <param name="nColumn"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void WriteDataIntoExcelSheet(Worksheet worksheet, ref int nRow, ref int nColumn)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn] = Student.Name;
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 1] = Student.Age;
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 2] = Student.JoiningDate;
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 3] = Student.SCourseIDName.CourseName;
            worksheet.Cells[nRow, nColumn + 4] = Student.SCourseIDName.CourseID;
            nRow++;
        }
    }
}
```

Student Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string CourseID { get; set; }

        public Student SCourseIDName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to solve your Null Reference Exception. Perhaps `vm` is null because `listview.Items` is a collection of `Student` not a collection of `IEnhancedListObject` and the `as` cast is failing?

Comment: Yes how to resolve this ?

Comment: @andrew i tried with student . I'm still facing the same issue. Could you please suggest some edits .

Comment: Can you post the specific code that is giving an error? Not a screenshot.

Comment: @andrew Im getting the error in ListViewExcelExporterExtension class i have posted the code. Iam getting error while calling WriteHeaderintoExcel and WriteDataIntoExcel

Comment: @andrew could you please help me out ? Waiting for your answer

Comment: @andrew i think the error is due to null value in vm object in ListViewExcelExporterExtension class. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Post the code for the Student class.

Comment: @andrew i have posted the code for student class. i have used the class from this url https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90473/Enhanced-ListView-Operations-Using-MVVM

Comment: As I suggested in my first comment, you are obtaining items from the listview which are `Student`s and then trying to cast to `IEnhancedListObject`. This fails and results in a null value because `Student` is not an `IEnhancedListObject`. Even if it were, you then call `WriteDataIntoExcel` but this is a method of `ViewModel` not `Student` so that would fail anyway (but the code doesn't get that far as `vm` is null).

Comment: Furthermore, your `WriteDataIntoExcel` doesn't take a `Student` (as one might expect). It uses a `Student` property on the `ViewModel` which doesn't seem to be set anywhere.

Comment: Also, why is `FillCourseIds` a collection of `Student`s? And why is the `SelectedCourseIdName` a `Student`? This whole architecture seems quite muddled.

Comment: I think the item should be closed as it seems like a debugging or homework exercise. Not that I wouldn't be happy to help, but it isn't the purpose of SO, which requires terse questions which allow for well-targeted answers that can be useful for future visitors. I suggest you try discussing with colleagues/mentors. Perhaps you could also try Reddit csharp.